# Response has no attribute 'username'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I try to return a custom Response for my generics API view but it does not work since I get 'Response' object has no attribute 'username' error when the API is called

Here's what I've done so far:

I handle the DoesNotExist exception error then return a Response (from django rest framework).

```
class UniqueEmailAPI(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
  permission_classes = [
    permissions.AllowAny,
  ]

  serializer_class = UserSerializer

  def get_object(self):
    email = self.request.data['email']
    try:
      return User.objects.get(email= email)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
      return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

UserSerializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email')
```

Exception Log:
[Stacktrace](https://gist.github.com/jhefreyzz/4d0e8921ee7eabb17ed67433b66a7a05)

Comment: This code does not contain any reference to `username`.  Please post the actual code, along with the full error traceback message.

Comment: Where's the complete exception?

Comment: Are you including the `username` field in your serializer?

Comment: updated the question with additional information

Comment: Did you by any chance name something else `User`, thus overriding a reference to the `User` model?

Comment: I think the serializer is trying to serialize your `Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)` response. You need to raise an error instead by using something like [`get_object_or_404`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) for the framework to know to return an error response and not serialize the response as if an object is being returned.

Comment: @Delena Malan your suggestion works. I use django shortcuts get_object_or_404 method I get the desired result. Thank you

Comment: @RicardoRaz cool :) I posted it as an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your serializer is trying to serialize your `Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)` response. It will try to serialize anything you return from `get_object` with your serializer unless you raise an error.

You can raise a 404 error using Django's [`get_object_or_404`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) method for the framework to know it should return an error response instead.

You could do something this:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
get_object_or_404(User, email= email)
```